# Create bearer token for Cloud Endpoints with custom authentication

Tags: python, jwt, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to configure Cloud Endpoints as a front end for GKE. As part of such I'm manually trying to create a jwt. But when I try to use it as a bearer token I get the following response.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 08 Feb 2021 16:28:06 GMT
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer, error="invalid_token"

{
    "code": 16,
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
            "detail": "auth",
            "stackEntries": []
        }
    ],
    "message": "JWT validation failed: Bad JWT format: should have 2 dots"
}
```

I create a private and public key using openssl

```
openssl genrsa -out jwt-key 4096
openssl rsa -in jwt-key -pubout > jwt-key.pub
```

Then I use Python to create the JWT itself

```
import jwt
import datetime

private_key = open('jwt-key').read()
#public_key = open('jwt-key.pub').read()

aud = 'https://echo.api.some.com'
payload = {
    'iss': 'iss',
    'sub': 'sub',
    'aud': aud,
    'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
    'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
}

token = jwt.encode(payload, private_key, algorithm='RS256')
print(token)
```

I use the output of the above Python script as argument to my http Authorization header

```
Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN
```

I have also uploaded the public key to a storage bucket and referenced that in my openapi specification but I'm pretty sure that's irrelevant in regards to my error.

Any clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at this error: `Bad JWT format: should have 2 dots`, from past experience, I think JWT token strings generally have a format like this `first.second.third`. Does your token string look different? (For security reasons, I would suggest **not** posting your actual token string in your question for now.) From [this website](https://jwt.io/) it looks like these parts might relate to `header.payload.verify_signature`.

Comment: Also, are you using `PyJWT` for the `jwt` module part? When I use that and run your Python script (after running the openssl commands) with Python 3.6.5 on a Linux-based OS, I get a generated token that contains two dots.

Comment: @summea - You're right, I messed up. If you make your comment into an answer I'll accept

Comment: No problem about that! I hope things are working as expected, now! Please let me know if something more needs to be added to the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment and my comments from earlier:

The error that says `Bad JWT format: should have 2 dots` makes it look like the problem might be related to the token string itself. JWT strings should normally have two dots in them, and I think the format generally looks like this: `header.payload.verify_signature` according to the example on the [jwt.io website](https://jwt.io/).

If your token string doesn't have two dots in it, perhaps part of the token string is missing and might need to be regenerated using your script.

When I tried running your script on my side, I used the [`PyJWT`](https://pypi.org/project/PyJWT/) module for the `import jwt` part and ran this on Python 3.6.5 on a Linux-based OS. After running the openssl commands you listed and then running your script, I ended up with a generated JWT string that has two dots within it.